# Why does navigation not work after login in angular

Tags: angular, navigation, jwt, router

I'm learning spring boot and angular, i need your help. 
When handling with JWT authentication, router.navigate() doesn't work despite it returns the JWT token. If I use console.log after the router navigation, it's also executed. 

 Here's the concerned method:

```
handleJWTAuthLogin(){
this.basicAuthenticationService.executeJWTAuthenticationService(this.username,this.password)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(this.username)
      console.log(data)
      this.invalidLogin=false
      this.router.navigate(['welcome',this.username])
    },
    error =>{
      console.log(error)
      this.invalidLogin=true
    }
  )
```

} 

This is my app-routing.module.ts 

`{path:'' , component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'login' , component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'welcome/:name' , component:WelcomeComponent, canActivate:[RouteGuardService]},
  {path:'logout' , component:LogoutComponent, canActivate:[RouteGuardService]},
  {path:'**' , component:ErrorComponent}`

Comment: by reading only this code I can not understand what is the issue. Can you please provide working demo or more detials ?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. It actually returns the token from the backend.                                                    {token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJpbjI4bWludXRlcyIsI…_IeUUaF90FMTA_9MlxbNkmoMHdUdbsinWY2ad0rVlf9pVxW4Q"}

Comment: Is there any error on the browser console?

Comment: No there is no error and the console.log(data) before router.navigate is working fine

Comment: Does the route of the `welcome` work? I mean if you write it as url into the browser, can you see the wished component?

Comment: Yes it works. I deleted the canActivate from the app-routing to test if the route works

Comment: Can you please update the question with the configuration of the routes? I mean the content of `app-routing.module.ts` for example. If you use lazy loading, than the routing of the lazy loaded module of `welcome` component also.

Comment: ok bro i will update my question